# How can I discover Apple TV's on my network?

Tags: transport-protocol, network-discovery

I have tried Googling for Apple TV and ports, and I've even reviewed the [List of TCP and UDP ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) on Wikipedia, and I can't find the information I need.

Is there a TCP port that all Apple TV's listen on so that it can be identified using a port scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple TV's will respond on TCP port 3689, 5000, 7000, 7100 and 62078

Source: nmap 7.40 against an Apple TV.

```
nmap -O 10.110.60.28

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-03-10 12:26 W. Europe Standard Time
Nmap scan report for 10.110.60.28
Host is up (0.013s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
3689/tcp  open  rendezvous
5000/tcp  open  upnp
7000/tcp  open  afs3-fileserver
7100/tcp  open  font-service
62078/tcp open  iphone-sync
OS details: Apple Mac OS X 10.7.0 (Lion) - 10.11 (El Capitan) or iOS 4.1 - 9.3.3 (Darwin 10.0.0 - 15.6.0)
Network Distance: 4 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 41.81 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple Bonjour protocol use Multicast DNS, which has been normalized in [RFC6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) and [RFC6763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6763).

It uses multicast IPv4 address `224.0.0.251` or IPv6 address `FF02::FB`

An bonjour enabled device will announce itself by multicast; so what you have to do is to examine traffic sent to 224.0.0.251 (with TCDPUMP, wireshark or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the link below it mentioned that

> These network ports are used by Apple TV for communications on your network.
>
> - TCP port 123 is used to communicate with a network time server.
> - TCP port 3689 is used to communicate with iTunes while using the iTunes Library Sharing feature.
> - UDP port 5353 is used by Apple TV for automatically finding computers with iTunes on your network using Bonjour.
> - TCP port 80 is used for communicating with podcast servers.
> - TCP port 80 and 443 are used for basic and secure communications with the iTunes Store via the Internet.
> - TCP port 53 is used for regular DNS.

https://www.administrivia.com/resources/apple-tv-tcp-and-udp-ports-and-protocols-used/